# How to prove that the set $S:=\{(u,v,\sin(u)\cos(v)):u,v \in [a,b]\}$ is connected?

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Exercise:
Given the Set $S:=\{(u,v,\sin(u)\cos(v)):u,v \in [a,b]\}$ show that $S$ is a connected Set.

From a intuitive viewing point the connectedness is obvious.
My first thought was to use the Definition of connectedness but I tried something else first:

My idea is to use the fact that for a continuous function $f:X \rightarrow Y$ and a connected set $X$ the set $f(X)$ is also connected.

So one could write the Set S as parametrization
$f(x,y)=(x,y,\sin(x)cos(y))$

$f$ is obviously continuous
and $f([a,b]^2)=S$

Now $[a,b]$ is path connected so, in particular the set $S$ is connected.

Are my calculations correct?
Is there another way to show it? I am especially interested in a more "topological" prove. Hope someone could help me out with that.

Comment: That's how I would have done it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is absolutely correct and I can't imagine that there is a completely different way to do it.

Note, however, that the set $S$ is the *graph* of the continuous function
$$f : [a,b]^2 \to \mathbb R^2, f(u,v) = (\sin u , \cos v).$$
But the graph $G(f) = \{(x,f(x)) \mid x \in X \} \subset X \times Y $ of a continuous function $f : X \to Y$ is always homeomorphic to the domain $X$. In particular, $S \approx [a,b]^2$.